# JavaScript playing with string Reveal Triangles

Tags: javascript

Hello guys i have to change this:

> abcdexgh
>
> bbbdxxxh
>
> abcxxxxx

to be looking like this:

> a*cde*gh
>
> ***d***h
>
> abc*****

but it looks like this now :

> a*cde*gh
>
> ***d***h
>
> abcxxxxx

```js
function revealTriangles(arr){
    var result = arr;
    for ( var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        for ( var j=1; j<=arr[i].length-1;j++){
            if(arr[i+1]!==undefined){
                if (arr[i][j]==arr[i+1][j]&&arr[i][j]==arr[i+1][j+1]&&arr[i][j]==arr[i+1][j-1]){
                  result[i]=arr[i].replace(arr[i][j],'*');
                    result[i+1]=arr[i+1].replace(arr[i+1][j+1],'*').replace(arr[i+1][j-1],'*').replace(arr[i+1][j],'*');
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<result.length;i++) {
        console.log(result[i]);
    }
    for (i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        console.log(arr[i]);
    }
}
var arr= ['abcdexgh','bbbdxxxh','abcxxxxx'];
revealTriangles(arr);
```

now i have added to print on the console both arrays in order to check if one will change and the other will not. the problem is i change both at the same time while i write to change only result. or i can make it with only one array but still i cant change the last row of the array . any hints ? thanks.

Comment: so a "triangle", if I understand this right, is when a single character on one line is matched by three identical ones at the same offset - 1 on the next line, and optionally 5 at offset -2 on the next, etc? are there other cases, like a right-angle triangle, or top-down?

Comment: Wow, i know we developers have a tendency to overengineer, but... ehh..  go read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace again. And while you're at it, check out this cool https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map.

Comment: At the moment your question lacks any explanation on the purpose of your code (aka What do you want to achieve?) Further it looks a lot like a students exercise. StackOverflow is not the place to solve your homework! Please consider reading this answer for more details: http://bit.ly/1P20m2A

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line of code :

```html
if(arr[i+1]!==undefined){
```

It simply skips the last element, because arr[i+1] in this case is undifined.

Answer (score 0):

After the first  iteration the array will be:

a* cde* gh

***d***h

In the second iteration, you are trying to match * with x which will not be true.
Hence the result is :

a * c d e * g h

***d***h

abcxxxxx